# Google Places API: is there a yearly limit of requests?

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3, web-scraping, web-crawler, google-places-api

I created a Python crawler in order to **scrape** Google Places API, I called it [Fantail](https://github.com/francesco1119/Fantail), and since 2 weeks doesn't works any more: it always returns `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`.

At the beginning I taught there was something wrong with my code, maybe I broke my code??? How is that possible if it was on GitHub?

Then I checked [someone's else **scraper**](https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places)  with my API key and the result is the same: `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`.

[image]

So I checked with Postman, and the `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` is there too:

[image]

I checked my Google API Console at around 23:22 and everything looked fine, not so many requests:

[image]

Then I checked the requests per day: come on... the 22 of July, 2 weeks ago I **scraped** like crazy before reaching the `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`, how can it stop me now?

[image]

So then I moved to this dashboard and I taught: maybe there is a limit per year or per month?

[image]

I don't know what else to try.

I have worked a lot with Google Places API in the last year, I know quite well when I'm pushing too hard. As you can see by the dashboard I haven't queried too much the API today, what is going wrong?

I see this happening in the last 4 days.

**Has Google Places API changed in the last weeks or so?**

Comment: Have you provided a credit card/enabled billing on your account? [change announcement](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/important-updates#billing_changes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a change, that maps, routes and places API are not free to use anymore, you will now get api calls worth of 200$ each month for free, but I think you have to enable billing for your APIs to work again. This change applied on 16th of June AFAIK.

See: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing

EDIT: Your 16k API Calls will probably exceed this limit and you will have to pay for it. Google estimates around 11k Places-API calls to be included in that 200$.

Comment: this is a very sad news :(

Comment: Google decided to make Maps [its next billion dollar business][1] by **raising prices 14 times and decreasing free usage limit almost 30 times**, all with minimal notice period [1]: https://www.inderapotheke.de/blog/farewell-google-maps

Comment: Yes those are some bad news for all those small to mid-sized projects and the prices are really high now. The problem is, like your link said: Google maps is just the best product available :(